# Export xsd element to a new xsd file

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have an xsd file with multiple elements called messages. This messages contain other elements defined in this huge xsd, which contain elements defined too in the xsd, and such. Let's call those elements "dependencies" of the message.

I only want to use one of this messages, so I'd like to have only this xsd message element and all the "dependencies" it needs in a new xsd file.

Investigating I've concluded it may be possible using XSLT, but I don't have the XSLT knowledge to know if this is even possible. Is it? Is there any tool that can do this?

Comment: Am I correct that you want to generate an xsd file from an xsd file? On what exact condition? It is possible, but it is a bit more complex.

Comment: @ChristianMosz You are indeed correct, the condition would be "element with name X and all the elements it depends on", "depending on" meaning those other elements are part of the element X (or are part of element Y, which is part of element X).

Comment: Detecting elements with specific childs, parents and attributes could be quite tricky. I do not really have a short and simple solution for this. But I have worked with xsds before so I know for sure it is possible. I would not recommend to try this if not completely necessary.

Comment: @ChristianMosz Thanks Christian, will look into it for a while and if I don't find a way I guess I'll stick to the whole big xsd file then.